# decipher this modified sum operation,

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

This is crossposted from Math.SE, the original question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615278/maths-puzzle-logic)

$1+2+3+4 = 61$

$2+3+4+5 = 52$

$3+4+5+6 = 51$

$4+5+6+7 = 50$

$7+8+9+10 = ?$

Comment: Ugh, do you HAVE to use $+$ and $=$ for these?

Comment: @Deusovi, why not? I think it is nicer this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}7+8+9+10&\to\text{Seven}+\text{Eight}+\text{Nine}+\text{Ten}\\&\to\text{S}+\text{E}+\text{N}+\text{T}\\&\to\text{Alphabet}_{19}+\text{Alphabet}_{5}+\text{Alphabet}_{14}+\text{Alphabet}_{20}\\&\to19+5+14+20\\&=58\end{align}